# Jquery in apex 4 Click event help

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an image that is in my apex application with the id tag of submit_button. I want to display an alert when the user tries to click this image but for some reason nothing is happening. In my header on the page I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">   

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit_button').click(function) {
           alert('hi');
        }
    });

</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why that doesn't work (it doesn't work for me either, I just tried), but it is very simple to do via a dynamic action with the following properties:

- Event = click
- Selection Type = DOM Object
- DOM Object = submit_button
- "True" Action = Execute Javascript Code
- Fire on page load = (unchecked)
- Code = alert('hi');