# Having issues redirecting to another page on closing of modal dialog page

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have page 1 from which I open a modal dialog page - page 2. Now when I close the modal dialog, I want to be redirected to page 3. On page 2 I have a button that has a dynamic action defined where on button click two actions take pace: Page Submit (with an after submit branch out to page 3) and Close dialog. Once I click on the button, dialog closes but the user stays on page 1, not going to page 3.

Comment: do you have any code to catch the click action outside the modal?

Comment: not sure what do you mean. I added a dynamic action to a button that is on the modal

Comment: yes so when someone clicks the close button on the modal, they get redirected but when they click outside the modal they are not redirected and the modal just closes, right? So you need to capture that click even outside the modal and if the modal is open at the same time, redirect the user to the next page

Comment: but at this point it is not even working when they do click on the button

Comment: figure out the container for the modal and attach the action to that as well. code examples will help a lot. [check this out also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522303/jquery-in-apex-4-click-event-help)

Answer (score 2):

If you have branch, you don't need to close dialog..

Another option is to travel through pages using PL/SQL-JS combination that redirects to URL after running code on server.

1. create a hidden, unprotected item called P2_TARGET
2. create a button with action defined by dynamic action,
3. add a dynamic action onClick for that button, with two true actions:

   a. Execute PL/SQL code, submit P2_Item, return P2_TARGET

   ```
   declare
       js_code varchar(4000);
   begin
       js_code := REGEXP_REPLACE(
                    APEX_PAGE.GET_URL (
                        p_page => 3,
                        p_clear_cache => 3,
                        p_items  => 'P3_Item',
                        p_values => :P2_Item
                    )
           ,'\,this\)'
           ,q'<,$('#p1Region'))>' -- jQuery of event source
       );

       apex_util.set_session_state('P2_TARGET', js_code); 
   end;
   ```

   b. Execute Javascript code:

   ```
   eval($v('P2_TARGET'));
   ```

and that's supposed to do the trick

Comment: Thanks! That is pretty much what I have except I execute PL/SQL from page load dynamic action and my PL/SQL, setting the value of P2_TARGET is a little different. What is `#p1Region`? Is that the static ID of the region on the modal dialog page?

Comment: exactly, this is the static ID of the region on the modal dialog page, and writing this here helps utilising the "Close Dialog" dynamic action

Comment: I did that and when I click the button, nothing happens. So I started debugging and it worked as soon as turned debugger on. But does not work without debug

Comment: I work on apex 18.2, the apex_page.get_url might work differently on older versions.
other than that, I suggest checking the P2_TARGET item and seeing how it looks (and of course - make sure to return P2_TARGET after the plsql, and that the item has a saved session state )